# Why does printf("\x10\x01\x48\x08 %x %x %x %x %s") read from memory address 0x90480110?

Tags: c, security, memory, printf

I'm taking a class on secure coding and the Format vulnerability. I thought I understood the basics of printf(), but it seems my grasp is more tenuous than I thought.

I'm struggling with understanding:

```
printf ("\x10\x01\x48\x08 %x %x %x %x %s");
```

Typically, `printf` has a a string with format specifier in it and a variable as argument, but there is just one argument here. Here, `printf` is reading from location `0x90480110` (because the machine is in little endian). Additionally, `%x` is causing the stack pointer (ESP) to move 4 bytes. So, essentially this like saying `ESP - 0x20` (I'm assuming this is a 32-bit machine). Then, `%s` reads from that address. Is my assessment of this line of code correct?

I'm confused about a few things, though.

When we gave `printf` the address `\x10\x01\x48\x08`, I'm confused as to why it read from that position. Is this `printf` quirk? You supply an address and it will read from that position?

How are the format specifiers moving the stack pointer? I thought they were just a way for the compiler to interpret the type of data.

Edit:
This was my source: [https://web.ecs.syr.edu/~wedu/Teaching/cis643/LectureNotes_New/Format_String.pdf](https://web.ecs.syr.edu/%7Ewedu/Teaching/cis643/LectureNotes_New/Format_String.pdf)

Comment: There are no arguments provided for the format specifiers -- undefined behavior.

Comment: You did give no arguments to printf but the format string. Now printf just takes whatever junk in memory where it thinks the (non existant) five arguments are and thus you get undefined behaviour.

Comment: And you did not give printf the address `\x10\x01\x48\x08`, you gave it a single format string starting with bytes `\x10\x01\x48\x08`.

Comment: @Jabberwocky I added a source from where I got the info. It states that it uses %x to move printf's pointers towards the format string and then reads from the address.

Comment: To understand the document you linked to, you need to have some understanding of how the program stack is managed at the hardware level. This is something one might learn in an assembly language course. The document makes use of several prerequisites about argument handling that are often not applicable in modern platforms, so you should not expect the code to “work” on any platform outside of one designated for use in that course. Diving into the details of this specific exercise is not a good question for Stack Overflow.

Comment: That said, you are misinterpreting what is happen. The program has some buffer that has received user input. It calls `printf` and passes it that buffer by giving the address of the first byte of the buffer as the first argument to `printf`. (No program should ever pass user input as the first argument to `printf`.) The conversion specifiers in the string tell `printf` to go looking for arguments of various types. On the platform the document presumes, the arguments would be passed on the stack, after the first argument to `printf`.

Comment: In the particular situation the document hypothesizes, the buffer is at an address 20 bytes greater than the address where the program put the first argument to `printf`. If `printf` had proper arguments, the second `unsigned int` argument would be four bytes after the first argument, the third 8, the fourth 12, and the fifth 16. So the `%x` conversion specifiers tell `printf` to look for `unsigned int` values in those locations. Then the `%s` argument tells it to look for a pointer to a `char` in the next argument location, which would be 20 bytes after the first argument.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Yes, I have taken assembly and reverse engineering. And taken a computer architecture course. I understand how arguments are handled. You push an the argument onto the stack and then to access the argument, you dereference [EBP+8] to access the parameter. The format specifier string is one string argument, how is that %x moves the stack pointer.

Comment: At that address, there is the buffer containing the user input. So, in this hypothetical situation, `printf` would take the first four bytes of the user input as a pointer to a `char` and would print the data from that address in memory.

Comment: @HappyJerry: `%x` does not move the stack pointer.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Thank you, that was a source of my confusion. You've answered my question.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm struggling with understanding:

`printf ("\x10\x01\x48\x08 %x %x %x %x %s");`

It's fairly straightforward: you're telling printf() to output a line that begins with four hexadecimal values (three of which are non-printing) and then format five values separated by spaces. But, you don't supply input for those values, so this is an invalid line of code.

I suspect what you're trying to do is:

```
printf("%x %x %x %x", 0x10, 0x01, 0x48, 0x08);
```

but this is just a guess.

Comment: That would be the goal if I were just trying to print hexadecimal characters. The code snippet could be found here: [link](https://web.ecs.syr.edu/~wedu/Teaching/cis643/LectureNotes_New/Format_String.pdf)

Comment: OK, I don't pretend to be an expert, but...I've been using printf() since the Reagan administration, and this is the first I've ever seen mention of this alleged functionality. I can't even get that line to compile, though it's possible that some combination of switches might permit it. In any event, it's not really much of an "attack;" it sounds to me like the lecturer is grinding an axe. But in any event, the premise behind your question, while consistent with the lecture notes, is IMO flawed.

Comment: I couldn't either and I was confused about that as well. Thank you for your insight. I appreciate it.

Answer (score -1):

You basically did something you are not allowed to do.  You provided format specifiers to the printf function, but didn't provide any variables.  The values of the variables are normally pushed onto the stack, which is where printf will get them.

So if you didn't actually put anything on the stack (which printf cannot know), it will still read from the stack to be able to print the specifiers you provided, resulting in random data being printed.

The string you provided `\x10\x01\x48\x08` is not an address, it's just four characters specified using hexadecimal numbers.

Some compilers will check the specifiers you have provided with the variables you are passing to see that they match. Not all though.

Comment: This was my source https://web.ecs.syr.edu/~wedu/Teaching/cis643/LectureNotes_New/Format_String.pdf

Comment: The source essentially states that %x moves the stack pointer to move towards the format string. I don't know a %x would manipulate the stack pointer which points towards the top of the stack.